# Inconsistent behavior when calling #'funcall with a macro

Tags: functions, elisp-macros, funcall

I would have thought that both of the `funcall`'s the follow would have yielded the same result, but they don't and I'm trying to understand why.

```lisp
(defmacro test/z () "z")
(funcall (function test/z)) ;; => "z"
(funcall (eval `(function ,(intern "test/z")))) ;; => Invalid function: test/z
```

Looking at the arguments of each call, they evaluate to the same thing:

```lisp
(eq (function test/z) (eval `(function ,(intern "test/z")))) ;; => t
```

What really has me scratching my head that is that if I use `defun` instead of `defmacro` `funcall` then works in both calls..

I think I'm missing something in my understanding and I'm hoping someone can straighten me out. I'm reading the elisp info manual, but haven't found anything.

What's going on here?

Comment: You have probably run into undefined behavior. The [Elisp manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Calling-Functions.html#Calling-Functions) says

"The argument FUNCTION must be either a Lisp function or a primitive
function.  Special forms and macros are not allowed, because they
make sense only when given the unevaluated argument expressions.
‘funcall’ cannot provide these because, as we saw above, it never
knows them in the first place."

Comment: @NickD It **is** undefined behavior if it is explicitly excluded in the manual even if the reasoning does not fit the OP's use-case.

Comment: Thank you! I should have read the documentation more carefully.. If one of you will write up an answer, I'll happily accept it to give you credit.. Since funcall does specifically call out that it doesn't work on macros I think that whatever behavior results shouldn't be relied upon. Although, it would be helpful if funcall enforced it's restriction, but that's my opinion. If I want to dynamically call a macro like this I can use: `(eval (list (intern "test/z"))`, which is what I'll do.

Comment: tylerware wrote: "If one of you will write up an answer, I'll happily accept it to give you credit..". @NickD That's your part. Best regards, Tobias.

Comment: Done - thanks @Tobias.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`funcall' is not supposed to be called with a macro as the FUNCTION argument. The [Elisp manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Calling-Functions.html#Calling-Functions) says:

> The argument FUNCTION must be either a Lisp function or a primitive function. Special forms and macros are not allowed, because they make sense only when given the unevaluated argument expressions. ‘funcall’ cannot provide these because, as we saw above, it never knows them in the first place.

However, that does not explain why `funcall` does not complain on the first call (that may be a bug). Wrapping it in `(function ...)` seems to make a difference in whether `funcall` will get an error or not in the macro case. The more common (?) method of passing the symbol to `funcall` does the right thing according to the doc:

```el
(defmacro test/z () "z")
(funcall (function test/z)) ==> "z"
(funcall 'test/z) ==> invalid function: test/z

(defun func/z () "z")
(funcall (function func/z)) ==> "z"
(funcall 'func/z) ==> "z"
```

Comment: I opened a [bug report](https://debbugs.gnu.org/cgi/bugreport.cgi?bug=41864).