# Call apply with a macro

Tags: functions, elisp-macros, apply, funcall

Is there a way to expand a macro using a list of arguments? I tried using `apply` but then I get an error that the "function" `my/x-becomes-nil` is invalid.

```lisp
(defmacro my/x-becomes-nil (variable x)
  `(if (eq ,variable ,x)
       (setq ,variable nil)))

(let ((q 2))
  (my/x-becomes-nil q 2)
  ;;(apply 'my/x-becomes-nil (list q 2)) ;; How to make this work?
  q)
```

Comment: Since macro arguments are not evaluated, "dynamic" macro calls in general can only happen from within other macro bodies, or through the use of [`eval`](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Eval.html).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Inconsistent behavior when calling #'funcall with a macro](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/59066/inconsistent-behavior-when-calling-funcall-with-a-macro)

Comment: Also similar to a recent question about special forms https://emacs.stackexchange.com/q/62727

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No. As (elisp) [Calling Functions](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Calling-Functions.html) tells us, for `funcall` (and it lets us know that `apply` is the same):

> Special forms and macros are not allowed, because they make sense only when given the unevaluated argument expressions.  `funcall` cannot provide these because, as we saw above, it never knows them in the first place.

I suggest that you think about what you are *really* trying to do, i.e., the reason why you think you need/want to apply a macro to a list of args. There might be an [X-Y problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) here.

Comment: I see. I don't quite see why the macro call is not possible since the arguments are not evaluated (I have a list of arguments or forms) so substituting the list of arguments into the macro definition should be possible theoretically.

Comment: `funcall` and `apply` are themselves functions -- so by the time they call their function argument, the arguments to be passed to that function have likewise already been evaluated.  I.e. if you call `(apply 'foo X Y Z)` then `'foo`, `X`, `Y`, and `Z` have all been evaluated before `apply` does anything at all.  This is the "it never knows them in the first place" part of the quote -- the *un*-evaluated arguments are not seen by `apply` at all.

Answer (score 0):

```
(defmacro my/x-becomes-nil (&rest args)
  (let* ((two-args (= (length args) 2))
         (var (funcall (if two-args #'car #'caar) args))
         (val (funcall (if two-args #'cadr #'cadar) args)))
    `(when (eq ,var ,val)
       (setq ,var nil))))
```

Expands identically when called either as `(my/x-becomes-nil q 2)` or `(my/x-becomes-nil (q 2))`. Note that the list literal in the second case is *not* quoted.